# kendo ui window not centering correctly

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-window

I have an issue that the Kendo Window does not center correctly.

Here is a simple fiddle that demonstrates the issue.  So there is room for the kendo window to show without the browser vertical scroll bar, but the kendo window center method, puts it off center, and forces the browsers scroll bar to appear.

[image]

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/codeowl/QKPN6/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="testWindow">
    <p>here is the test content here is the test content</p>
    <p>here is the test content here is the test content</p>
    <p>here is the test content here is the test content</p>
    <p>here is the test content here is the test content</p>
    <p>here is the test content here is the test content</p>
    <p>here is the test content here is the test content</p>
    <p>here is the test content here is the test content</p>
    <p>here is the test content here is the test content</p>
    <p>here is the test content here is the test content</p>
    <p>here is the test content here is the test content</p>
    <p>here is the test content here is the test content</p>
    <p>here is the test content here is the test content</p>
    <p>here is the test content here is the test content</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oWin = null;
    $('#testWindow').kendoWindow();
    oWin = $('#testWindow').data('kendoWindow');
    oWin.center();
});
```

Please show me how I can get the kendo window to center correctly.

Comment: Not understand what do you want. Window centered correctly, in center of preview. Explain in more details.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Look at the picture in my question.  The kendo window is not centred vertically as there is space above it, and because of that space it makes the vertical scroll bar appear in the browser, as seen in the picture.  If the kendo window vertically centred correctly there would be less space at the top, and no vertical scroll bar in the browser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem is solved :) Try.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oWin = null;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    $('#testWindow').kendoWindow({});
    oWin = $('#testWindow').data('kendoWindow');
    oWin.center().open();
    $('#testWindow').closest(".k-window").css({
        top: h/2 - $('#testWindow').parent()[0].scrollHeight/2
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QKPN6/9/)**

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to work this out mate.  It does give me the desired result.  As a paying customer of Telerik, I think I will also put in an official support request as really the component should do this out of the box, without the need for this workaround.  Appreciate your time.