# KendoWindow Doesn't Center Vertically On Mobile/ Tablet

Tags: css, kendo-ui

I'm using kendoWindow to display popups on an internal web app of ours and centering it to the screen using the code below.

```
kendoWindow({
    paramerers...
    }).data("kendoWindow").center().open();
```

This works fine on desktop applications (even when using tablet sizes in chrome dev tools)

The issue I'm having comes from actual mobile devices where the center code puts the popup at the very bottom of the screen, cutting part of it off.

Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening on mobile/ tablet devices, and not the equivalent sized desktop window?

My speculation is that this is being caused somehow by the onscreen keyboard being off screen, but I could be off base.

Both desktop and tablet are running Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a duplicate of [kendo ui window not centering correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758731/kendo-ui-window-not-centering-correctly), check out the answer there, it should fix your problem.